# How to use several sectioning trees (Chapter, Section....) in parallel and in the same document

Tags: sectioning

I am actually writing my thesis and I would like to insert one of my paper inside, but keeping the original numbering. The simplest way to understand what I am trying to do is to give an example:

Chapter 1

```
1.1 Chapter 1 Section 1
1.2 Chapter 1 Section 2
...
```

Chapter 2
    2.1 Chapter 2 Section 1 (Paper to be inserted)
        1 First section of the paper
           1.1 First subsection of the first section of the paper
           1.2 Second subsection of the first section of the paper
           ...
        2 Second section of the paper
        ...
    2.2 Chapter 2 Section 2 (Comments on the paper)
Chapter 3
    3.1 Chapter 3 Section 1
    3.2 Chapter 3 Section 2

So the question is how to start a new structure tree without stopping the main one. I don’t need the second structure to be in the table of contents so one possibility would be to replace all the  `\section{blabla}` by `\section*{blabla}` and then manually replace all the `\ref` by their corresponding reference number manually. This is quit a long process and each time there is a modification in the paper, everything as to be updated manually.
If anybody know how to do that automatically

Best

Florian

Edit; 
With the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
%Here I want to include one of my paper already published, using my template but keeping the same notation as the original paper.
\sectionPaper{Section 1 of the Paper}
\subsectionPaper{Subsection 1 of the Paper}
\subsectionPaper{Subsection 2 of the Paper}
\sectionPaper{Section 2 of the Paper}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

The `\sectionPaper` of course is not working but it is here only to show what I am trying to do. I would like something similar to the package `multibib` that that for example creates a new bibliography when the suffix Paper for i.e. is added to `\cite (\citePaper)`. Here I am looking for something that creates a second new and independent sectioning tree when I call for example `\sectionPaper`. Hoping that it is more clear now, Best.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a 'preliminary' version of `xassoccnt` (please use the bugfix version from here until the improved version has been uploaded to CTAN etc: [xassoccnt v0.5a](http://siebenfelsen.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/xassoccnt.0.5a.tar.gz)

The core feature are the `\BackupCounterValues` and `\RestoreAllCounterValues` macros that backup and restore the counter values and provide a separate 'structuring' tree. The counter values are restored at the position of the macro usage. Please note that `hyperref` is not confused by this since the `\theH....` macros are changed and restored at well, placing new anchors.

In order to make the new 'tree' consistent, the usage of `\counterwithout` etc. from `chngcntr` might be appropiate. This depends on the level of the new tree.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
%Here I want to include one of my paper already published, using my template but keeping the same notation as the original paper.
\hrule
\BackupCounterValues[resetbackup=true]{chapter,section,subsection,figure,table,equation}
\section{Section 1 of the Paper}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of the Paper}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of the Paper}
\section{Section 2 of the Paper}

\RestoreAllCounterValues
\counterwithin{section}{chapter}
\hrule
\section{Regular section from first chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\hrule
\BackupCounterValues{chapter,section,subsection,figure,table,equation}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\section{Section 1 of another Paper}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of another  Paper}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of another  Paper}
\section{Section 2 of another Paper}
\section{Section 3 of another Paper}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of another  Paper}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of another  Paper}
\section{Section 4 of another Paper}

\RestoreAllCounterValues
\counterwithin{section}{chapter}
\hrule
\clearpage

\section{Regular section}

\end{document}
```

[image]