# "\input only part of a file" and keep numbering

Tags: input, catchfile

I would like to create an excerpt from a script that I have TeX'ed as a compendium of the most important statements (theorems & definitions).

The question
[**\input only part of a file**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file)
has an [answer by Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4952/74942) that supposes the usage of [catchfilebetweentags](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/).
I did that and it is working just fine, but ...

## How do you keep the original numbering?

The above mentioned method using the catchfilebetweentags package allows me to make corrections of errors in the main file and the summary at the same time. For the sake of comparability, I would prefer to have the same numbering also. Though the numbering is reset.

---

Note:
I could imagine a solution by putting a `\setcounter{counter}{value}` in front of each statement but inside the tags. However, this is a very inconvenient way as it is inelegant and involves much more work.

---

**Edit (MWE):**

Taken from [this site (by Giacomo Drago)](http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/3/latex-loading-equations-from-an-external-file.html)

File that contains tags which should be included

```
% Equations dictionary
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

% Begin document
\begin{document}

%<*eq001>
\begin{equation}
F\left (x_1,\dots,x_n,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n},\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_n\partial x_n},\dots
\right)
\end{equation}
%</eq001>

\begin{equation}
    a = b + c
\end{equation}

%<*eq002>
\begin{equation}
u_x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \quad\quad\quad
u_{xy}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right).
\end{equation}
%</eq002>
% A bunch of other equations...
\end{document}
```

File that includes

```
% http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/3/latex-loading-equations-from-an-external-file.html
\documentclass[a4, 11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\loadeq}[1]{%
   \ExecuteMetaData[equ.tex]{eq#1}%
}


\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \loadeq{001}
    \blindtext
    \loadeq{002}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you make it more clear by adding examples of two files? and is write18 an option?

Comment: Fpr the counter values see the package `xassoccnt` package and it's `\BackupCounterValues` and `\RestoreCounterValue` features please, as I have shown in my answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245680/how-to-use-several-sectioning-trees-chapter-section-in-parallel-and-in-th -- please download the bugfixed version (v.0.5a) of `xassoccnt` from my website.

Comment: @touhami, added MWE (note that my question aims at a theorem counter - in case that changes something). Concerning `\write18`: I am not familiar with that option, though on first sight it seems like quite some work to set up. I would prefer some out of the box solution with some package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer , I had a look at your answer there and it looks quite promising. As far as I understood, it is used to insert a complete text with independent numbering. Would that allow to include just a single section or theorem whilst maintaining the numbering ? To make it more clear: I do not want any consecutive numbering, but the numbers that each part had in the original file/pdf. (Even if that means it goes like 1.03, 1.06, 1.07, 1.13, 2.13, 2.01, ...)

Comment: the problem here is that you will have (let say) eq1, <eq 2> and eq2 or how do you plan equation `a+b=c` will be numbered?

Comment: @hillbilly: No, that's a completely different approach then, unless you explicitly set the counter values to have those 'weird' values like `1.03` etc. but you could use the set counter approach directly then

Comment: @touhami , as mentioned before (see my comment directed to Christian) it would mean that some equation was skipped (e.g. eq1, eq2, eq4).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer could one achieve that behaviour by saving the counter in the *import-file* and restoring with each import ? I don't know how the imported file is processed, but if it was just one extra command, then the amount of extra work was reasonably low enough.

Comment: @hillbilly: You mean `\BackupCounterValues` within your imported file? That should be possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. The idea is to capture almost every thing but display only needed parts

first file (with tags)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
%<*tag>
\lipsum[1]
Here we go
%</tag>
%<*atag> 
\begin{definition}
some bla bla
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
more bla bla
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
some bla bla
\end{definition}
%</atag>
%<*btag>
\begin{definition}
some bla bla
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
more bla bla
\end{theorem}
%</btag>
%<*ctag>
\lipsum[1-2]
%</ctag>
%<*dtag>
\begin{lemma}
more bla bla
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
more bla bla
\end{theorem}
%</dtag>
%<*etag>
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{example}
some bla bla
\end{example}
%</etag>
\begin{theorem}
more bla bla
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

final file

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newtoks\temptoken

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}% capture part1
\setbox0=\vbox{\the\temptoken}%  skip part1
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{atag}% capture part2
\the\temptoken % display part2

\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{btag}% capture part3
\setbox0=\vbox{\the\temptoken}%  skip part3
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{ctag}% capture part4
\setbox0=\vbox{\the\temptoken}%  skip part4

\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{dtag}% capture part5
\the\temptoken%  display part5
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried your solution with a slight adjustment, that was having all statements use the theorem counter. It seems to work :), really nice. Could you maybe elaborate on how this works ? Especially the difference between `\ExecuteMetaData[file]{tag}` and your `\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{dtag}` and the `\setbox` as well as `\temptoken` (your comments say it shoul display part 2 only).

Comment: @hillbilly ok i will try

Comment: `catchfilebetweentags` package define 3 commands (6 if starred version) `\CatchFileBetweenTags` to be used as above `\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{dtag}` where `\temptoken` is toks register or a macro command where the content is saved in case of  toks register (as above) we need `\the\toksrigstername` to display the content.

Comment: `\ExecuteMetaData[file]{tag}` is equivalent to `\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}\the\temptoken` i.e. it capture the content and display it immediatly.

Comment: the command `\CatchFileBetweenDelims` is similar (with slight difference) to `\CatchFileBetweenTags` please see documentation.

Comment: In my answer i used  `\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{dtag}` this save part between `dtag` into toks `\temptoken`. If we need this part we just need to display it with `\the\temptoken` if we don't need it (but we need to skip it) we display it into a save box `\setbox0=\vbox{\the\temptoken}`.

Comment: Nice! I think that explains it well enough. If I am not mistaken, then your `% skip part5` should be `% display part5` as it is not printing into a `\setbox0` , right? - Why not add this information to the answer itself ?

Comment: 1) yes you're right thanks. 2) I will try.

Comment: I created another question based on your answer! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once

Comment: @hillbilly i will see :-)

Comment: Is it possible, to make this compatible with SyncTeX? (I already posted a separate extended question [\input only part of file, but preserve synctex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438075/input-only-part-of-file-but-preserve-synctex) about this.)

Comment: @kdb I don't know how synctex works so I have no idea.