# How to get correct counters/numbers with \catchfilebetweentags

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, include

I often need to include pieces of text from document A (my main manuscript) in document B (letter to the editor explaining how I revised the manuscript). Both documents are full fledged Latex documents, so \include is not an option. It seems that generally, `\catchfilebetweentags` is the way to go. I understand how I can use tags to "import" text blocks from A to B. However, the imported text does not show counters like numbered sections or figure numbers. Instead, it shows ??.

I found a related question, but I am not sure how I can apply the answer to my problem:
[“\input only part of a file” and keep numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296417/input-only-part-of-a-file-and-keep-numbering)

Is there a way to "import" the correct counter numbers? Thanks for your help!

THE MAIN "MANUSCRIPT" main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} \label{introsection}

\begin{figure} \label{myfigure}
    \caption{An empty figure.}
\end{figure}

%<*tag>
This is section \ref{introsection} of the main file. We present the results in Figure \ref{myfigure}.
%</tag>

\end{document}
```

THE "LETTER TO THE EDITOR"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags} % load the package

\newcommand{\loadRevision}[1]{ % define command to load figures
    \ExecuteMetaData[main.tex]{#1} % call the package macro to 
}

\begin{document}
The revised Introduction now reads as follows:

\loadRevision{tag}  
\end{document}
```

OUTPUT
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are references included, storing the counter values in another manner isn't necessary, as those values have been stored already.
Use `\usepackage{xr}` (or with `hyperref` `\usepackage{xr-hyper}` to retrieve the 'counter' values (rather: the reference content) after saying

`\externaldocument{main}`

Here is the 'letter' file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags} % load the package
\usepackage{xr}

\externaldocument{main}
\newcommand{\loadRevision}[1]{ % define command to load figures
    \ExecuteMetaData[main.tex]{#1} % call the package macro to 
}

\begin{document}
The revised Introduction now reads as follows:

\loadRevision{tag}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. So simple once you know it. Thank you!