# destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) error when using \input

Tags: hyperref

I have seen that a lot was already written on the error-message "destination with the same identifier (name{page.})". However in my case, no solution does the trick.

Here is a MWE that should replicate the mistake:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,onehalfspacing]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}
\graphicspath{02\_images}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,pageanchors=false,hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Declaration Of Authorship}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Some example...

\chapter*{Statement Concerning Publication}
Some example...

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
Some example...

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{Intro}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some example...

\chapter{Theoretical Framework}\label{TF}
Some example...

\chapter{Findings}\label{Fin}
Some example...

\chapter{Conclusion}\label{Con}
Some example...

\end{document}
```

I assume that the mistake comes from `\hyperref` but the follow solution does not do the trick:

```
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pageanchors=falsehidelinks]{hyperref}
```

The Pdf-File seems to be fine, but the error bothers me...

Comment: Try `pageanchors=false` as an option. The question is however, if the anchors are still correct, i.e. the linking leads to the correct position

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I already tried that option (sorry for not mentioning), does not solve the problem though.

Comment: @FlavioFrei: One error by me: It's `pageanchor=false`, not `pageanchors`, that fixes the problem for your MWE (at least), sorry about that. But `fixltx2e` is deprecated, since all features have been incorporated into the LaTeX core.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that did the trick. I still don't unerstand why since I simultaneously resolved the issue with `fixltx2e` and did some other alterations, too. The mistake is gone though.

Answer (score 3):

There were two things that I did to make the error go away:

1. Remove `fixltx2`, since apparently the required code is now part of the LaTex core.
2. Add `pageanchor=false`to `\hyperref`as an option.

Comment: `pageanchor=false` is certainly a way of shutting off all warnings about duplicate page anchors: this is because it suppresses generation of page anchors altogether (as its very name says!).  But what if you do need such anchors in your document, for example, in order to have working links to pages in an Index?  `hyperref` manual is not very clear about this, but I take the liberty to refer you to [an answer I gave 20 days ago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298582), in the hope that the experiments which I made and described there may give you some useful tip.